# lookup from multiple columns & "circular dependency was detected" error

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I need to put together a deals dashboard to help sales activity. The purpose of this is to match customer requests with supplier offers, so show if there is a business opportunity.
The problem is that customers and suppliers usually have several different identifiers for the same product. Like this:

Supplier offers:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCRIj.png)

Customer requests:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ok7kR.png)

In order for the offers and requests to match, I need to create a data table with the unique products with the product name and ID we want to use. Next to the Main IDs, I need to enter all the alternative IDs that I met in offers and requests. Something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZCMQ.png)

To be able to make relationship between these tables, for both I added a calculated column at the end of both the offers and requests tables with the following DAX formula:

Main ID = LOOKUPVALUE(product_data[Main ID],product_data[Main ID],'supplier offers'[ID])&LOOKUPVALUE(product_data[Main ID],product_data[ALT ID 1], 'supplier offers'[ID])&LOOKUPVALUE(product_data[Main ID],product_data[ALT ID 2], 'supplier offers'[ID])&LOOKUPVALUE(product_data[Main ID],product_data[ALT ID 3], 'supplier offers'[ID])&LOOKUPVALUE(product_data[Main ID],product_data[ALT ID 4], 'supplier offers'[ID])&LOOKUPVALUE(product_data[Main ID],product_data[ALT ID 5], 'supplier offers'[ID])

So it found the main IDs for all offers and request like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxcz4.png)

But after, when I wanted to make relationship between supplier offers and product_data by linking to main identifiers to each other, **Power BI shows "Circular dependency was detected**: supplier offers [Main ID]" (and the same with customer requests.)

I want to make relationship in order to use the Product Names and Main IDs from the product_data in my visuals.

What should I do to avoid this error? Is there an other solution to lookup values from multiple columns?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One piece of advice is to add an image description to your linked pics. Good question, though!